# Batch requests throws 404 not found

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-api-java-client

I'm using the Google Apps Java client library to develop an Android application. I am trying to send a batch request as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/batch).

This is my request code for the discovery endpoint, which you can see has a `batchPath` field with "batch" as value:

```java
BatchRequest batchRequest = mApi.batch(); 

mApi.insert(mEntity).queue(batchRequest, callback); 

batchRequest.execute();
```

However I keep getting a `404 error`. I have already deployed my rebuilt project and double checked the API url. Why is my request not reaching my generated endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Cloud Endpoints doesn't support REST batching (which the Java client library is trying to use). One can use JSON-RPC for batching, but most client libraries are REST-based, rather than RPC-based.