# HTTP 404 error when requesting spreadsheets/:batchUpdate endpoint

Tags: java, google-sheets-api, google-api-java-client, http-error

I have this method that is using the java API for writing to the google sheets.

```
public UpdateCells writeValue(int row, int col, String value)       
        throws IOException {
    List<Request> requests = new ArrayList<Request>();
    List<CellData> values = new ArrayList<CellData>();

    values.add(new CellData().setUserEnteredValue(new ExtendedValue()
            .setStringValue((String) value)));
    requests.add(new Request().setUpdateCells(new UpdateCellsRequest()
            .setStart(
                    new GridCoordinate().setSheetId(SheetId)
                            .setRowIndex(row).setColumnIndex(col))
            .setRows(Arrays.asList(new RowData().setValues(values)))
            .setFields(
                    "userEnteredValue,userEnteredFormat.backgroundColor")));

    BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest batchUpdateRequest = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest()
            .setRequests(requests);
    sheetsService.spreadsheets()
            .batchUpdate(workSheetId, batchUpdateRequest).execute();
    return this;    
}
```

I wrote it some time ago, but I am pretty sure it was working all right. now that I tried to use it again on some other project I am getting a 404 error.

> **404.** That’s an error.
>
> The requested URL
>   `/v4/spreadsheets/:batchUpdate` was not found on this
>   server.  That’s all we know.

This is the stacktrace

> com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found
>   at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:146)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1065)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)

I used different methods from the google api [documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values#writing_to_a_single_range), but I was getting the same error.
any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Does this question apply? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29833473/batch-requests-throws-404-not-found?s=3|36.3860

Comment: @tehhowch Thanks. it might,but I think i followed the official google [documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values#writing_to_a_single_range) on java but that didnt work either!

Comment: @SkarosIlias any luck with this issue? I'm having the same issue and I suspect it's because I'm trying to persist my sheetService.

Comment: @Proximo to be honest I dont even remember. I see that I still have that code on my application, but havent used that for ages. not sure if it even works. sorry

Answer (score 2):

Okay I figured this out.

If your `spreadsheetId` is invalid then you'll receive a 404 since the `spreadsheetId` is part of the URL.

So double-check that your `spreadsheetId` is correct and not being nulled about by a process like was the case for me.